# With CSS Paged Media, is it possible to "stick" or absolutely position block elements to the top or bottom of a page?

Tags: css-paged-media, css-print

In the CSS spec for paged media, is there a way to "stick" a block element to the top or bottom of a printed page, and have the text flow around it?

I have some image blocks inline with other HTML (the block is a DIV containing and image and a caption DIV). The problem is that they're tall-ish -- some of them are a half-page in height.  If there's not enough remaining room on the page for them, they will move to the next page, leaving significant whitespace on the prior page.

I'd like to be able to absolutely position them to the top or bottom of whatever page they call on, and have the text continue around them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want "CSS Page Floats".  See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-floats-3/.